# Redirect asset requests to https, along with mod_rewrite for pretty URLs

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-rewrite, https

I'm having trouble changing all requests to https, while using the following for pretty URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?([-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /?p=$1
RewriteRule ^/?([-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /?par=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

I've tried adding the following directly beneath the above (and removing the L directive above) but get redirect errors:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you behind an SSL proxy (as your directive suggests)? In what order have your placed these directives? Are you already canonicalising the www / non-www somewhere?

Comment: I am not behind an SSL proxy. The directives are in the order I have above. Canonical is being set with the canonical meta tag, but that is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
> ```

The `X-Forwarded-Proto` header is only set by a proxy server (or a malicious client), so, unless you are behind an SSL proxy of some kind then you should not be using this (it will likely result in a redirect loop if you do).

Any canonical redirect (HTTP to HTTPS and/or non-www to www) should appear *before* your internal rewrites.

Try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^/?([-\w]+)$ /?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([-\w]+)/([-\w]+)$ /?par=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

I've added the `L` flag to your first internal rewrite.

The `\w` is just a short-hand character class for `[_a-zA-Z0-9]`.

(If this is in `.htaccess` then the `/?` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is not required.)

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) only when you are sure it's working OK, to avoid caching issues while testing. You will need to make sure the browser cache is clear before testing.

Ideally, you should also be canonicalising the www / non-www here as well, rather than rely on a canonical meta tag. This could be combined with the above HTTP to HTTPS redirect. For example, to redirect to www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

However, this particular redirect does assume you don't have any other subdomains.

Comment: Super helpful, thank you! So far it seems to be working perfectly.

Comment: Also very good to know that I can canonicalize in htaccess, instead of just the meta tag.

Comment: You're welcome. The `rel="canonical"` (`link` element) - assuming that's what you mean by "meta tag" - is particularly helpful when you have slight variations in a URL (eg. with a URL parameter that controls sorting) where all should be accessible (so a redirect is not appropriate), but only one is canonical. Something like `www` canonicalization should be done at the server level, since you want _users_ to see only one.